# showing a different datatable on button click

Tags: jquery, datatables

hi i am creating an application with two tables one for student results and another one for student contacts i am using datatables to display the data.
when the document loads the student results table is showing perfectly i have a button that when clicked should replace the student results table and show the student contacts table 
i have tried the solution below it is not working

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var otable = $('#student_results').datatable({'sAjaxSource': "server.php"});

$("button#contacts").click(function(){

$("div #results table").replaceWith('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"     
class="display" id="example">
<thead>
<tr><th width="5%">id</th><th width="35%">name</th>
<th width="30%">number</th>
<th width="30%">department</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="3" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot><tr><th width="5%">id</th><th width="35%">name</th>
<th width="30%">number</th><th width="30%">department</th></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>');
example.fnReloadAjax('server_processing.php');
});


});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="results">
<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="Result">Results</button>
<button id="contacts">Contacts</button>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="2%">result_id</th>
      <th width="20%">reg_no</th>
      <th width="30%">name</th>
      <th width="15%">unit code</th>
      <th width="30%">unit title</th>
      <th width="3%">grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <br>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th width="2%">result_id</th>
      <th width="20%">reg_no</th>
      <th width="30%">name</th>
      <th width="15%">unit code</th>
      <th width="30%">unit title</th>
      <th width="3%">grade</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

please help.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: try by using .innerHtml instead of .replaceWith

Comment: What is the `example` object from which you call the method `fnReloadAjax('server_processing.php')`? Was that defined somewhere on your page?

Comment: By the way : `<table class="Template Hidden">...bla bla bla...</table>` and `.replaceWith($('.Template').clone().removeClass('Template').html());` looks clearer to me.

Comment: Dude, i am not sure about datatable, but you better You like this
$("div #results table").replaceWith('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"'
+'class="display" id="example">'
+'<thead>'
...
...

Comment: Indent your code right, it's a pain in the ass to read, I did it for you but I need 2k rep to submit the edit >.<

Comment: putvande the error is "datatable warning(table id= 'student_results':  ) Requested unknown prameter '4' from the data source for row 0" and i think error is ocuuring since the column names are different for the two tables

Comment: @cars10 am sorry it shouldn't be example in fnReloadAjax it should be otable just a typo

Comment: i have tried all solutions above but still not working pagination shows correctly but data is not showing...how do i solve this error "datatable warning(table id= 'student_results': ) Requested unknown prameter '4' from the data source for row 0".

Comment: Have you checked what your `server_processing.php` actually delivers? Is it a valid JSON structure? And what does fnReloadajax do? I have not found it in the datatables documentation (I am completely new to datatables!)?

Comment: am using firebug to check if server_processing is working and the script is giving the correct response i.e i can see the contacts in the firebug xhr but unfortunately the data is showing up in the table...it still gives me the same error...i am not sure how to go about it.